# Next.Js: localhost:3000 not working in browser

Tags: next.js, localhost

Nex.js - localhost:3000 is not working in the browser. It keeps "running, running" and never opening, or when it opens it doesn't update any of the edits you made?

I had this problem, I researched a lot and couldn't solve it. I solved it this way:

1 - Before opening the visual code, open your program folder in next, and delete the first folder, next.
2 - Open the visual code folder, go to the package.json file and click on debug, inside the package.json file.
3 - At the top, some options will appear, click on "next dev"

This will solve it. The whole problem is it's in the next folder. There is a conflict with the browser, so by deleting the next files this conflict ends.

Comment: You'd have to describe your specific circumstances (is anything else running on port 3000 or is it free? How did you create the project, is it create-next-app? Did you follow the next.js docs for running the next app? and the problem (what do you mean by "it is not working") some more, please.